# how to pass image from database to the html using django

Tags: django-templates, django-views

my view is like this

```
image1=UserProfile.objects.get(user_id=request.user)
            print(image1.user_image)
            update_profile = UpdateProfileForm(initial={'first_name':server1.first_name,'last_name':server1.last_name, 'phone_no':server2.phone_no,'Emg_no':server2.Emg_no,'area_code':server2.area_code,'landline_number':server2.landline_number, 'shop_name':server2.shop_name, 'shop_address':server2.shop_address, 'country':server2.country, 'city':server2.city, 'website':server2.website})
            variables = RequestContext(request,
                                   {'group':group,'update_profile':update_profile,'timeline_list': timeline_li, 'updatepassword':ChangePasswordForm,'userimage':userimage,'image1':image1})
            return render_to_response(
                                      'registration/profile_try.html' , variables,
                                      )
```

and my html is like this

```
<div class="uiAvatarXLarge profileHighlightAvatar" >

                        <img  id="user_img"  alt="" class="img-rounded"   src="{% static '{{image1.user_image}}' %}" style="width:120%;cursor:pointer;">
                    </div>
```

but my image not displaying properly. can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `{{image1.user_image.url}}` in template